# SQLAlchemy query filter by field value in related table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to get devices which type is not `'TYPE_BLADE_SERVER'`. Please help write a query. My solution which i try:

```
result = Device.query.filter(DeviceGroup.type != ModelType.TYPE_BLADE_SERVER).all()
```

Which doesnt filter `device_group` table becouse `device_group` renamed to `device_group_1`. Sql query from sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT * FROM device_group, device
LEFT OUTER JOIN device_model AS device_model_1 ON device_model_1.id = device.model_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN device_group AS device_group_1 ON device_group_1.id = device_model_1.group_id 
WHERE device_group.type != % (type_1)s ; {'type_1': 'TYPE_BLADE_SERVER'}
```

Working solution but like sql hardcode:

```
result = Device.query.filter(text("device_group_1.type <> 'TYPE_BLADE_SERVER'")).all()
```

My models:

```
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostname = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    model_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('device_model.id'), nullable=True)
    model = db.relationship("DeviceModel", backref='devices', lazy='joined')

class DeviceModel(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'device_model'

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   group_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('device_group.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)

class DeviceGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device_group'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    models = db.relationship("DeviceModel", backref=backref("group", lazy="joined"), lazy='joined')
    type = db.Column(sa.Enum(ModelType), nullable=False)

class ModelType(enum.Enum):
    TYPE_BLADE_SERVER = 'TYPE_BLADE_SERVER'
    TYPE_ENGINEERING_DEVICES = 'TYPE_ENGINEERING_DEVICES'
    TYPE_DATA_STORAGE = 'TYPE_DATA_STORAGE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not_

```
from sqlalchemy import not_
result = Device.query.filter(not_(DeviceGroup.type == ModelType.TYPE_BLADE_SERVER)).all()
or
result = Device.query.filter(~DeviceGroup.type == ModelType.TYPE_BLADE_SERVER)
```

Comment: Operator not_ equal !=. Expression ~DeviceGroup.type produce error with sql WHERE (NOT device_group.type) = %(param_1)s'

I think my problem in table naming. Thx for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Copy answer link here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/8L1HWG7H27U|

Docs:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#the-zen-of-joined-eager-loading